# Is this invalid &(*_shmItr) == NULL where _shmItr is an List iterator

Tags: c++, stl

```
&(*_shmItr) == NULL
```

this is quite noob question but, I m newbie to C++.

in GCC 3.1.2 when you check _shmItr == NULL is perfectly fine, but as GCC 4.2.2
this is an error. I did google about the error. they says dereferencing and referencing again will solve the problem. and It did. I was happy. But as I m learning more about iterator. I feel may be this is passing the error, but not valid and can give runtime problem.
What is your suggestion to me ...

I did little research and found that

```
_shmItr == _shmItr.end()
```

Also serves the same purpose and more correct. please correct me if I m wrong.

basically we are trying to check if _shmItr is holding something invalid or not. before doing any operation.

Thanks in advance.

Here is the code chunk

```
_shpmtItr = _shpmtList.begin();

if(_shpmtItr == NULL)
{
   eaLogMsg << setid("APP_FAILED")
            << "_shpmtItr is NULL in some::few()"
            << endl;

   return APP_FAILURE;
}
```

This can tell you the scenario.
static

Comment: Iterators are a different, more general concept than pointers. An iterator may be implemented as a pointer, but you should never rely on that being so.

Answer (score 2):

Definately use `list::end` if you're checking to see if you've passed to the end of the list.  There's no guarantee that the next item after you've traversed every element in a list will be NULL.  It won't tell you if the item your pointer points to is valid.  Here's the way I'd use `list::end` if I were checking to see if my results were valid or not:

```
list<whatever>::iterator item = find( myList.begin(), myList.end(), value );
if( item != myList.end() )...
```

Because `find` returns the last item in the range you've given it to search on if no element exists.

That said, when you do `&(*something)` what you're doing is getting the address of the element the iterator points at which is perfectly valid code.  If you expect that the invalid items are going to be NULL then it works for your purposes.  If you don't know if they'll be NULL, that is another story.

So what code are you using?  Perhaps that could help us answer your question better.

Edit:

Looking at your code and seeing you use `list::begin()` and then checking it against NULL is bad unless your list is a list of pointers (or pointer like objects such as `shared_ptr`.)  I'd actually recommend you use `list::empty` to see if the list is empty rather than `myList.begin() != myList.end()`.  The meaning of that is crystal clear and should be easier to maintain in the future.